# Polygon color change function for multiple variables

Tags: thingsboard

[dashboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN3j3.png)

I am using thingsboard CE. I have the dashboard layout shown in the image and want to overlay a polygon on each rectangular switch. However, I want the color of each polygon to change depending on the value of the respective variable. The value of each variable can either be one or zero. If the value is zero, that specific rectangle should be red else it should be green. Data is received as follows:

state1: 1
state2: 0
state3: 1
state4: 1
state5: 1

Telemetry is sent from an arduino uno

```
{
var state1 = dsData[dsIndex]['state1'];
if (state1 == 1) {
    return "red";
} else {
    return "green";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify, I will assume that you are storing your "state" string on Device attribute level because that's some logical way to go if you don't have some complex situation.

You can't have that telemetry on one Device, and also you can't have it on Device level.
So, first of all, in rule chain you need to split every state into it's own. For that take a blue script and make a message like this:

```
[
  {
  msg: msgOfState1,
  metadata: metadataOfState1,
  msgType: POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST
  },{
  msg: msgOfState2,
  metadata: metadataOfState2,
  msgType: POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST
  },
]
```

After that you need to save every state value as individual Asset (because polygons can be only assigned to Assets). For that, use "Create Relation" node in rule chain to essentially make originator change to Asset and then put a "Save attributes" after it). 1 State = 1 Asset!

Once you do that, you will be able to draw a polygon on that image and also make a color change with dependence of that state variable.

This is a bit complex if you just started with it, so fell free to ask related questions.